# "Positional arguments must occur before named arguments. Try moving all of the positional arguments before the named arguments" error flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, containers

I am trying to use a container to display a TextField, but the container doesn't like the order of what I did apparently. Here is my code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("New Grocery List"),
    ),
    drawer: AppDrawer(),
    Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Default TextField',
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
);
```

}
I found the container code in a different thread where it supposedly worked, so I think that it's happening because of something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are missing the Scaffold's body. Try to put `body:` before Contaiter.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("New Grocery List"),
    ),
    drawer: AppDrawer(),
    body: Container( //put body in this line
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Default TextField',
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
);
}
```

Comment: wow, I should've known, I'm not that new to Flutter, thanks for replying!

Comment: It's alright. But if it resolved, you can accept my answer.

Comment: yeah, sorry about that, it said I had to wait a little bit

Comment: No problem. Tnks